# How can I include the subtracted rows from this query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Consider this query:

```
 select count(*) from 
(
select pickle_id,
       pickle_code
from   pickles
where  pickle_code='DILL'
group  by pickle_id,
          pickle_code /* Returns 1000 rows */
minus 
select pickle_id,
       pickle_code
from   relish inner join pickles on relish_id=pickle_id
where  relish_code ='BURGER' /* Returns 1500 rows */
) 
/* Complete query returns 900 rows */
```

**Question:**

How can I write query that returns the original 1000 rows and 
    only the 100 that were subtracted from the minus query?

Results should total 1100 rows (1000 + 100 that were subtracted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
select pickle_id,
       pickle_code
from   pickles
where  pickle_code='DILL'
group  by pickle_id,
          pickle_code /* Returns 1000 rows */

union all
(
select pickle_id,
       pickle_code
from   pickles
where  pickle_code='DILL'
group  by pickle_id,
          pickle_code /* Returns 1000 rows */
intersect 
select pickle_id,
       pickle_code
from   relish inner join pickles on relish_id=pickle_id
where  relish_code ='BURGER' /* Returns 1500 rows */
)
```

Comment: Should it not be `UNION ALL`? The 100 that are duplicates will be removed just using `UNION` and only 1000 rows will be returned?

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, that would be everything before the `minus`:

```
select pickle_id, pickle_code
from   pickles
where  pickle_code = 'DILL'
group  by pickle_id, pickle_code;
```

EDIT:

The answer to the question in the comments is:

```
select count(*)
from ((select pickle_id, pickle_code
      from   pickles
      where  pickle_code='DILL'
      group  by pickle_id, pickle_code /* Returns 1000 rows */
     ) intersect 
     (select pickle_id, pickle_code
      from   relish inner join pickles on relish_id=pickle_id
      where  relish_code ='BURGER' /* Returns 1500 rows */
     ) 
    ) p;
```

Comment: The 100 rows that got subtracted are the ones that interest me. How can I identify them?

Comment: replace `minus` with `intersect` in your original query

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) from (
    select pickle_id,
           pickle_code
    from   pickles
    where  pickle_code='DILL'
    group  by pickle_id,
              pickle_code
    union all
    select pickle_id,
           pickle_code
    from   relish inner join pickles on relish_id=pickle_id
    where  relish_code ='BURGER' and pickle_code='DILL'
    group by pickle_id, pickle_code
)
```